# Inconsistency when using strlen

Tags: c++, strlen

The code below manifests inconsistency if you change `SIZE` from 7 to 8. If `SIZE` is 7, the `strlen(chars)` returns 7; if `SIZE` is 8, the `strlen(chars)` returns 9, which is no more equal to `SIZE`.

I am aware of the fact that `strlen` works for C-string and that `chars` below is not a C-string (because it does not have a null termination character  `\0`). But I am currently debugging other people's code and trying to understand why the described inconsistency occurs even though `strlen` does not seem to be used in the right way.  Any idea?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#define SIZE 7
int main ()
{
  char chars[SIZE];

  for (int i=0; i<SIZE; i++) chars[i]='A'+i;
  std::cout<<"strlen(chars)   = "<<strlen(chars)<<std::endl;;
  std::cout<<"SIZE   = "<<SIZE<<std::endl;;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are invoking **undefined behaviour**.  Anything can happen.  Practically speaking, you are at the mercy of the contents of the stack surrounding your `chars` variable.

Comment: The `strlen` function will go out of bounds looking for the terminator. When and where it will find something it interprets as the terminator is unknown and indeterminate.

Comment: @Olive As I said in the post, I know strlen should not have been used in that way.

Comment: This is also the perfect example to tell those "other people" that they should use `std::string`, so all these problems could be avoided.

Comment: @zell What's your question then? Wanna hear someone say "Undefined behavior is undefined."?

Comment: If you want to understand why your platform is giving you this specific behaviour, when you know it isn't defined by C++, you're asking a question about the platform rather than the language. You haven't said what the platform is, but you probably need to debug at the assembly level to understand what's going on and why. And then - you can't depend on it not changing anyway, because it's undefined.

Comment: @BaummitAugen  I am simply looking for order in chaos.

Comment: @zell There is no order in UB, because undefined behavior is undefined.

Comment: Well, it's not defined by the language spec. It's entirely possible that some particular compiler/OS/architecture combination _does_ specify this behaviour as an extension, but OP _still_ hasn't told us what _any_ of those 3 things are (and it's probably unwise to depend on such an extension anyway, without a really good reason).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strlen:

> The behavior is **undefined** if there is no null character in the character array pointed to by `str`.

That means that anything can happen.